# I can't get a value of HTML tag using beautifulsoup python

Tags: python, web, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

Hey there is a website that I'm trying to scrape and there are values in the inputs that doesn't scrape as text
ONLY HTML
Like this

```
<input class="aspNetDisabled" disabled="disabled" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_EmpName" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$EmpName" style="color:#003366;background-color:#CCCCCC;font-weight:bold;height:27px;width:150px;" type="text" value="John Doe"/>
```

So what I want to do is just getting the Value ( John Doe )
I tried to put.text But it's not scraping it
This is the code

```
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content,'lxml')
    for name in soup.findAll('input', {'name':'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$EmpName'}):
            with io.open('x.txt', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as f:
                f.write (name.prettify())
```

Comment: First try to print `name.prettify()` in the console and verify if that is what you expect the value to be. That will help you with debugging the issue.

Comment: When I print name.prettify()  I get the code as HTML as above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are not getting a result when calling `.text` is since the "John Doe", is not in the text on the HTML, it's an HTML *attribute*: `value="John Doe"`.

You can access the attribute like a Python dictionary (`dict`) using `tag[<attribute>]`. (See the [BeautifulSoup documentation on attributes](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes)).

```
html = """<input class="aspNetDisabled" disabled="disabled" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_EmpName" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$EmpName" style="color:#003366;background-color:#CCCCCC;font-weight:bold;height:27px;width:150px;" type="text" value="John Doe"/>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
for name in soup.findAll("input", {"name": "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$EmpName"}):
    print(name["value"])
```

Output:

```
John Doe
```

Comment: OMG Dude. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

While the answer from [MendelG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68188315/15164646) works great, it could be a bit cleaner without using a `for` loop (*if you want to extract only one element*):

```py
>>> soup.find('input')['value']
# John Doe
```

Code:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

string = '''
<input class="aspNetDisabled" disabled="disabled" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_EmpName" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$EmpName" style="color:#003366;background-color:#CCCCCC;font-weight:bold;height:27px;width:150px;" type="text" value="John Doe"/>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(string, 'html.parser')

john_come_here = soup.find('input')['value']
print(john_come_here)

# John Doe
```

Comment: Thank you, But do you know how Can I make it print all the results not only the first result?

Comment: Because when I add FindAll instead of find it says TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: @Saleh07BR Of course! To better understand the context, could you provide the URL?

Comment: I solved it can you check my other question?